# Realm.io sorting result

Tags: realm

I am in a position to choose an embeded database for a mobile chat Android application.

The database will contain multiple object types but the most important is the chat object.

A chatroom may contain several thousand chat messages (with text and other data).
I therefore need to be able to get the chat messages in reverse date order.

Realm allows RealmResults to be sorted AFTER the query is being done.
I suppose that this means the sorting is made in memory after loading the result.

Is there a way to tell Realm to store the data already sorted so that it does not have to sort on the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emanuele from Realm here.

Realm does **not** do sorting operations in memory so your application will not suffer memory problems for such use case.

Thank you for trying us out and let us know if you need any help of information!

Comment: Hi. Does Realm support custom sort orders ? For example I have a table which has 3 fields: name of a geographical place, its latitude and longitude. I want to sort the result depending upon the distance from the current location (which will vary depending upon the user's location). Thanks